# Can I send email as different accounts using Gmail web interface?

Tags: gmail

I know that you can configure Gmail to gather email from multiple email services. But can you configure it to use them for sending messages?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Once you've set up another account in Gmail you can "send as" that account.

1. Go to [Settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general)
2. Go to the [Accounts and Import](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/accounts) tab
3. Under "Send mail as:" click the "Add another email address you own" link
4. This opens a pop-up window. Put the name you want to use and the email address you want to use. (You need to decide if you want to [treat the address as an alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338?ctx=gmail)); submit the form
5. On the next page, you need to define the SMTP server credentials for the address. (You used to be able to use Google's SMTP servers, but they removed that option.) Once complete, click "Add Account"
6. You'll receive an email message at the other address to confirm that you own/control it. Click the link in that message, and you should now have the address available to "send from" within Gmail.

When you're composing an email message, the `From:` will now be a drop-down where you can choose the address you want to use.

More information: [Gmail Help: Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)